# In Snap-ins chat can we display profile picture for agents dynamically?

Tags: snap-ins

I have one requirement where i want to display agent's profile picture in snap-ins chat. As far as i know we can only have agent avtar uploaded and that is too static But i wanted to know if we can display agent profile picture in snap-ins chat dynamically for every agent his own profile picture in chat window?

Answer (score 0):

From the standard ui, you won't be able to set it up dinamically. 
However, depends on your requirements, you can set the embedded_svc.settings.avatarImgURL param dinamically based on your business logic and see if that is fits for your needs.
For example: on different subsites you want to show different avatars because thats how you set up your omni-channel routing.
Documentation:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.snapins_web_dev.meta/snapins_web_dev/snapins_web_set_chat_images.htm#!